# How to write a SQL Server procedure to execute more than one query?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

.net web application development.

I am involved in a project regarding University. In this project I have to effect 3 table in a single
button click, for that I have to execute 3 queries at a time.

So my requirement is to write a procedure to execute 3 queries at a time.

Please help me to go forward.

thank you,
bye.

Comment: Are you using this stored procedure inserts / update the tables? Or there different select statement to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's the problem?

```
create procedure dbo.usp_3Queries
(
    @Variable1 int,
    @Variable2 int,
    @Variable3 int
)
as
begin
    update dbo.Table1 set Column1 = @Variable1 where Column2 = @Variable2

    update dbo.Table3 set Column3 = @Variable3 where Column2 = @Variable2

    update dbo.Table4 set Column3 = @Variable3 where Column2 = @Variable2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is very broad and unspecific.....

So you just write that procedure and execute the three queries....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedureNameHere  
     *possibly a list of parameter*
AS BEGIN
   -- Query #1
   DELETE FROM dbo.YourTableNo1
   WHERE (some condition)

   -- Query #2
   UPDATE dbo.YourTableNO2
   SET SomeColumn = SomeSIllyValue
   WHERE (yet another condition)

   -- Query #3
   SELECT (list of columns)
   FROM dbo.YourTableNo3
   WHERE (you guessed it - another condition)
END
```

We can't really help you much more unless you can provide

- table structures
- more details on the queries you want to run
- what kind of issues / problems you're facing